# How can I set or change a value of a concrete cell programmatically?

Tags: slickgrid

Using a **pure array as data source (not a DateView)** to initialize a SlickGrid, I want to change a value after grid creation on a specific row / column (a cell).

Here is the simple example, that can also be found as a [working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t3srcvu0/) and I want for example to change the value of "Duration" on row 3 ("Task 2") from "5 days" to "7 days".

```js
<div id="myGrid" style="width:400px;height:400px;"></div>   

<script>
  var grid;
  var columns = [
    {id: "title", name: "Title", field: "title"},
    {id: "duration", name: "Duration", field: "duration"},
    {id: "%", name: "% Complete", field: "percentComplete"},
    {id: "start", name: "Start", field: "start"},
    {id: "finish", name: "Finish", field: "finish"},
    {id: "effort-driven", name: "Effort Driven", field: "effortDriven"}
  ];

  var options = {
    enableCellNavigation: true,
    enableColumnReorder: false
  };

  $(function () {
    var data = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
      data[i] = {
        title: "Task " + i,
        duration: "5 days",
        percentComplete: Math.round(Math.random() * 100),
        start: "01/01/2009",
        finish: "01/05/2009",
        effortDriven: (i % 5 == 0)
      };
    }

    grid = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid", data, columns, options);
    grid.setSelectionModel(new Slick.CellSelectionModel());

    /* needed method */
    grid.setCellValue(2, 1, "7 days");
    /* or */
    grid.setCellValue(2, "duration", "7 days");

  })
</script>
```

It looks like a method like

```
grid.setCellValue(row, column, value);
```

does not exist.

Is there a way (or existing method I didn't found yet) to achieve this without using a DataView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use

```
data[2].duration = "7 Days";
```

and then refresh the grid:

```
grid.invalidateAllRows();
grid.render();
```

The grid only has display related helper methods, although you can get the data with `grid.getData()`. Editors, if you use them, contain code to extract the value from a row (`data[n]`) and write it to the editor UI, and then go back the other way.

Comment: Interesting, that the "data" array is still bind to the grid after initialization... But seams to work so far, thank you!

Comment: Yes, a copy is *not* made of that, and the grid is not fully rendered at init. The 'data' array is the data source used dynamically to generate only as many rows of UI as are visible to the user. This is why the grid is so fast.